# forcefully add delete button to uitableviewcell while gesture swipe called

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having one custom cell in my tableview.
I'm trying to show add delete button on swipe gesture.

In viewDidLoad I have written

```
showExtrasSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipe:)];
showExtrasSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
showExtrasSwipe.delegate = self;
[self.prospectTableView addGestureRecognizer:showExtrasSwipe];
```

Handler method of this gesture recognizer looks something like this

```
-(void)cellSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.prospectTableView];

NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.prospectTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

[self tableView:self.prospectTableView commitEditingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete forRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
}
```

Now the `commitEditingStyle` method gets called for every swipe.
But problem is that I'm not able to see the delete button which animates in background.

Comment: How you have added delete button on cell?

Comment: I have not added yet .. Thats the concern only.. How can i see the delete button which will animate as default delete button.